# Proof that in a field $x=0$ is equivalent to $x=-x$

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $x\in F$. If $x=-x$ and $1\neq -1$, then $$0=\frac{x+x}{1+1}=\frac{1+1}{1+1}x=x.$$
This means that the statement in the title is true if and only if $1\neq -1$.

But how do we know that $1\neq -1$ for an arbitary field?

Comment: This doesn't work in a field of characteristic 2. For example consider $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with addition and multiplication mod $2$. You have $1=-1$ and $1\neq 0$.

Comment: A better proof goes as follows. Let $K$ be a field of characteristic different from two. Then $x=-x$ is equivalent to $2x=0$. Since $2\neq 0$ it follows that $x=0$.

Comment: Remember that the characteristic of a field is defined to be minimum $n$ such that $1+ 1+\ldots +1$ (added $n$ times) is $0$, or the characteristic is $0$ if no such $n$ exists. So saying a field has characteristic $2$ is *equivalent* to saying $1+1=0$ by definition of characterstic.

Comment: @halrankard Thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But how do we know that $1+1\neq 0$ for an arbitrary field?

Completely valid question, and the answer is: you don't! There are fields for which $1 + 1 = 0$, called fields of characteristic $2$. The simplest example is the field with two elements, $\mathbb{F}_2 := \{ 0, 1 \}$, where $1 + 1 = 0$.

Indeed, in $\mathbb{F}_2$ (or any field of characteristic $2$) we have $1 = -1$ but $1 \neq 0$, so the result you are trying to prove is true only when the characteristic of the field is not $2$.